# Auto generate field with a certain format

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to generate a User Record Number automatically. When a new user is added, they get assigned a User Record Number. The User Record Number follows this format: “US-000000”. The first user added to a account will be User Record Number US-000001.

How to do this? Is there any way in mongodb to autoincrement on based on a format as in SQL Server?

Comment: check these links : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454271/auto-increment-document-number-in-mongo-mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, MongoDB does not feature any form of automatic incrementation, not even for the automatically generated `_id` fields, as this does not work well wit hthe clustered, non-centralised nature of the system.

The only way to achieve this is trying to work it out with atomar operations like `findAndModify` or similar, and create the incremented ID in your application.

As a suggestion, Keep a field like this in the collection:

```
{
    "_id": "incr",
    "n": 42
}
```

Whenever you add a new document, read the value via [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) and [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) it right away - that way your counter is always correctly incremented and you get the correct number to add.

Comment: Would be nice if you changed the operator mentioned to [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) which is the actual operator. For the record there is a documented tutorial on handling [auto-incremented fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the official manual.

Comment: Do will i need to create a new collection for this?

Comment: @Anup no you just put the document above in the same collection. As long as the `_id` won't overlap, there's no problem.

Comment: When i put the document above in the same collection..When i retrieve list of all users...this record also comes with everything null..!

Comment: @Anup Then add `_id : { $ne : 'incr' }` to your `findAll` query.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did... :)

Comment: This thing works in RoboMongo....but same query gives no results in my code...! `User.find({ '_id': { $ne: 'incr' } }, ....`

Comment: @Anup can't help your there, make a new question for that or search older ones.

Comment: As i solved this issue....further i found that my search query also brings a null record.....I think i should make a new collection specially for Auto Increment...!!